# How to avoid text box movement on Font size change in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

If I have a textbox with property 'Fixed', I have it set to a specific width, height and position. If I change the font size of the text in that box it will change Y position. I want the text box to remain in the same X,Y position no matter which font size I set. How can I do this?

Comment: Sketch tries to retain the Baseline Y position of text, both with text property set to Auto or Fixed. After keeping the Baseline Y position after changing fixed font size, Sketch forces the fixed text box to change Y position, in order to retain Length and Width measurements. I want Sketch to ignore retaining baseline and retain text box X,Y position instead.

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is to set the alignment to the center.

Like this image:

[image]

Then You can resize your font and it won't move in X,Y position.

It would just bigger in size.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't answer my question. I'm using a fixed box size.